# Frame size not applying? - XAML MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

**I am trying to make a frame a specific size but the frame seems to only match the size with components inside of the frame.**

I tried finding solutions but couldn't find anything, perhaps I am searching for the wrong things.

*The XAML:*

```xml
<ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Frame BackgroundColor="#303030"
                   Padding="8" CornerRadius="5"
                   HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500">

                <StackLayout Spacing="10">
                    <Label Text="Login" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <BoxView Color="{DynamicResource Primary}" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

                    <Entry Placeholder="Username" />
                    <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" />

                    <Button Text="Login" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Primary}" TextColor="{DynamicResource White}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

*What it looks like:*
[image]

*What I want it to look like:*[image]

Comment: Frame (and Border) are intended to wrap content. If you want a fixed size area, make a ContentView or a Grid with those dimensions. If you then want a border, you wrap it (no dimensions needed) with Frame or Border. NOTE: Frame is an older implementation, for backwards compatibility with Xamarin Forms. Consider Border instead. (If you get this working, with either Frame or Border, please add Your Answer below, showing the exact code that works.)

Comment: Thank you for your response Steve, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View toolmakersteve's response if you have this "issue" too!

*Code:*

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="400"
            HeightRequest="400">
        <Border BackgroundColor="#303030"
                   Padding="8">
            <StackLayout Spacing="10">
                <Label Text="Login" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <BoxView Color="{DynamicResource Primary}" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Username" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" />
                <Button Text="Login" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Primary}" TextColor="{DynamicResource White}" Clicked="LoginClick" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Border>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*Result:*
[image]